# Как работает функция file_exists?

Tags: php, циклы, функции

Нужно выводить в цикле картинки из папок, пока не переберёт все. Попробовал применить функцию **file_exists** которая **проверяет существование указанного файла или каталога** и таким образом, будет выполнять цикл пока не кончаться файлы в указанном каталоге, но почему-то конструкция **не работает**. Код вот такой:

```
<?php echo "<div class='hidden-container'>";?>

<?php

$img = 1;
$imgf = "/files/id$id/" .$img. ".jpg";

while (file_exists($imgf))

{

echo "<a id='thumb1' class='highslide' href='/files/id$id/$img.jpg'
            onclick='return hs.expand(this, inPageOptions)'>
        <img src='../files/id$id/" .$img. "_thumb.jpg' alt='" . $myrow["title"] . "'/></a>"; 
$img = $img +1;

}

echo "</div>

<div id='gallery-area' style='width: 620px; height: 520px; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid silver'></div>";
?>
```

**Внимание, правильный ответ:**

```
<?php echo "<div class='hidden-container'>";?>

<?php

$img = 1;
$imgf = "/files/id$id/" .$img. ".jpg";

while (file_exists($imgf)){
echo "<a id='thumb1' class='highslide' href='/files/id$id/$img.jpg'
            onclick='return hs.expand(this, inPageOptions)'>
        <img src='../files/id$id/" .$img. "_thumb.jpg' alt='" . $myrow["title"] . "'/></a>"; 
$img++;
$imgf = "/files/id$id/" .$img. ".jpg";
}
echo "</div>
<div id='gallery-area' style='width: 620px; height: 520px; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid silver'></div>";
?>
```

**Ответ автора вопроса:**
Нужно было реализовать вывод картинок из определённой папки, но перед этим определить сколько их там находиться. Выход нашёлся, возможно немного кривой, зато работает отлично!
    <?php 
$path = "files/id1/*_big.jpg";
$m = glob($path);
$col = count($m);
$col = $col +1;
?>

";?>
$img = 1;
$imgf = "/files/id$id/" .$img. "_big.jpg";

while ($img < $col) 
{

echo "
        [image: " . $myrow["title"] . "]"; $img = $img +1;

}
echo "

";

?>

Comment: Он, дорогой друг, может «не работать», если у тебя, например, отсутствует файл с именем `1.jpg`. Ну или `2.jpg` (тогда отработает один раз). Но что в твоем понимании «не работает», науке неизвестно.

Comment: А то и значит, что ничего не отображает хотя файлы такие есть. Хотя если по вашему: не выдаёт ошибок значит работает, тогда да!

Comment: Напишите результат вот такого:

    $img = 1;
    $imgf = "/files/id$id/" .$img. ".jpg";
    print_r(scandir($imgf));
    print_r(scandir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$imgf));
    print_r(realpath($imgf));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$path = '/images/*.jpg';
$m = glob($path);
print_r($m);
```

Смотрим, втыкаем, решаем, что делать с полученным результатом. ;)

Comment: =.= О тебе я в профиле уже написал.

Comment: Ну, никто же эту функцию не предложил. А это еще +вариант. =)

Comment: Вот те плюс за вариант.

Comment: Спасибо).  
Так вот как, оказывается, работает эффект перетягивания плюсиков...

Comment: Так и работает: приходит Линг, рисует заумный, короткий ответ, который работает... и перетягивает плюсики. =.=

Comment: Держи еще. Эффект надо воспроизводить )

Comment: Во, видал, а? Только пришел, уже дважды в репу плюс схватил. =.=

Comment: Подскажи, что и как? не могу разобраться, а то все только ржут а ответа работающего дать не могут!

Comment: @chech1 — извини, ты уже поднадоел малость. Начни с основ программирования, узнай, что такое циклы, потом файлы трогать будешь.

Comment: @cheh1, а ничего не делать - в массиве $m у вас уже хранятся адреса всех jpg из заданной папки.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
function getJpeg($path='/files/id$id/'){
$files = scandir($path);
$ret = array();
foreach($files as $file){
  if(preg_match('/\.jpg$/i',$file)){
    $ret[] = $path.$file;
  }
}

return $ret;
}

?>
```

Воть... А функция file_exists действительно проверяет существование файла. Только у вас она проверяет существование только одного файла.

Comment: Я сейчас нод исправил, посмотрите! Вроде всё правильно сначала для $img присваиваю 1, выводиться информция, затем увеличиваем на 1 проверяет существование файла выводит и т.д. или нет?

Comment: img-то вы меняете. А imgf - нет. Надо imgf менять на каждой итерации цикла, так как именно эта переменная проверяется

    while (file_exists($imgf)){
    //Ваш код
      $img = $img +1;
      $imgf = "/files/id$id/" .$img. ".jpg";
    }

Comment: По-моему, автор вопроса неисправим. Или тролль ))

Comment: Уберите $img=1 вначале цикла. Иначе цикл кончится только через 30 секунд.

Comment: Нафига внутрь цикла `$img = 1;` засунул? Опять одно и то же значение выставляешь.

Comment: Убрал $img = 1, пробую, не работает, затем скопировал код опубликованый как правильный ответ и тут ничего нового!

Comment: Что такое $id, который вы подставляете в строку?
И почему у вас разный путь в Эхо и в проверке файла?

Comment: id это id номер публикации в базе, он же название папки с картинками

echo "<a id='thumb1' class='highslide' href='/files/id$id/$img.jpg'// большая картинка
            onclick='return hs.expand(this, inPageOptions)'>
        <img src='../files/id$id/" .$img. "_thumb.jpg' alt='" . // миниатюра $myrow["title"] . "'/></a>";

Answer (score 1):

Внутри цикла `$imgf` обновляйте. А то у вас условие константное получается, все время один и тот же файл проверяет.

Лучше использовать `readdir`/`scandir`. Ведь в общем случае — до которого числа вы файлы перебирать будете?

Comment: Извиняюсь код был не тот прописан. Исправил!

Comment: Проблема та же.